# Someone is accessing my computer through remote desktop. How can i block that?

Tags: macbook-pro, remote-desktop

I have a mac book pro 8gb i5 core. While I was using a cam service online. Someone send me a link and I opened it by accident. Such link opened another window which appeared to load,but it never did. It send me back to the main page,then next thing i know it open up my desktops as if i had pressed f3, and I never pressed it.

I downloaded Sophos thinking it was a virus, ran it and it did not find anything. I figured it had to be someone controlling my computer for there is no other way to do that with the Dashboard.
How can i block that? because now it happens randomly, and whenever it does my computer gets super slow. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck 'Remote Management' in System Preferences -> Sharing

Comment: This is a good first start and might be all the malicious software did. It could be a package that allows remote log in on it's own and need to be cleaned, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ran a software package, there's no short cut to getting some help from someone that knows how to reinstall the OS and then clean out any un-needed files (or only bring back your documents and not your apps).

Luckily, you might be able to leverage gatekeeper on a freshly re-intalled Mac to catch the program starting if you restrict the machine to only run signed apps from the Mac app store until you are sure you have eliminated the bad settings or bad program.

1. Get a back up of your Mac - preferably with it disconnected from the internet.
2. Have someone verify the backup is good
3. Erase and reinstall - keeping the backup disconnected until you have a baseline secure system and then migrate things back keeping an eye on things and remote settings.

You could also block (or monitor) incoming network requests to locate the program that's running using a tool like Little Snitch and then proceed to clean the file that has compromised your Mac. Again, it will take some technical knowledge and patience which you can invest time, energy and money in or outsource that to someone that already has those skills.